# iOS get the view of a UITableViewCellAccessoryDetail

Tags: ios, uitableview, popover

I have a function I'd previously written to present a popover from a bar button item, now I'm trying to reuse it to show the popover from a cell accessory when the table is in edit mode.

I've tried

```
[self showPopover:[[theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] editingAccessoryView]]
```

but this is NULL.

Originally it's set with `[cell setEditingAccessoryType: UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton];` if that makes any difference.

And the popover function is

```
-(void) showPopover:(id)sender {
    ...
     [self.popOver presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender 
                             permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}
```

Any ideas please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about trying to display with:

```
- (void)presentPopoverFromRect:(CGRect)rect inView:(UIView *)view permittedArrowDirections:(UIPopoverArrowDirection)arrowDirections animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Just pass it your cell.accessoryView.frame as the "rect" argument.

Comment: I'd like to keep the function exactly as it is, it's used quite a lot and I don't want to go through and edit every occurrence of it, which I think is how you suggest doing it. In the worst case I can write a new one using presentpopoverfromrect, just trying to reuse as much as I can.

Comment: I mean I've used the function a lot, theres only one version of it. But wouldn't I need to edit everywhere it's called to pass different arguments? Maybe I wasn't clear, it's `[[theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] editingAccessoryView]` which is NULL